# Groovy collections - Finding an element that matches a condition

Tags: collections, groovy

I have a groovy collections which is an array, containing value starting from 0 through 'n'. I need to find a particular array index when a series of conditions occured. And,I do not need to scan through every value of the array but can jump across pre-defined intervals. For example, look for the condition for every 10 values in the array. Can someone tell me a way to do this?
For example, I want to do somehting like this below

```
def alltimes = [0 . . . . . 10000]
def end_time = 10000
def time = 0
while(time <= end_time)
{
    // check the condition for alltimes[time]
     if(condition_satisfied){ 
         println "condition satisfied at time ${time}"
         break
     }
    time = time + 50  
}
```

When i explored all available methods of array, i did not find any one which can allow to jump variables instead of just one as in methods each, eachwithindex.

Seems like I need to use metaclass and create a new method?

Comment: Can you come up with an example?  It might help explain what you need better...

Comment: Still don't understand... Where is the collection in your example?

Comment: Sorry, i have edited my post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` for this:

```
def allTimes = 0..10000

Closure<Boolean> checkCondition = { all, single ->
    single > 300
}

​(0..10000).step( 50 )​.find { time -> ​checkCondition( allTimes, time ) }​
```

Which is ripe for currying:

```
def allTimes = 0..10000

Closure<Boolean> checkCondition = { all, single ->
    single > 300
}

​(0..10000).step( 50 )​.find checkCondition.curry( allTimes )​
```